# Getting an error when trying to run Dradis on web browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very newbie at these kind of softwares and programming stuff, so...

When i try to run the adress that dradis gave me on the startup (0.0.0.0:3000) i'm getting this Internal Error on Firefox:

Missing 'secret_token' and 'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment, set these values in 'config/secrets.yml'

I searched a lot about, but, didnt find a solution that fit my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dradis maintainer here. Looks like you cloned the git repo but didn't run `./bin/setup`.

Instructions to get the git repo up and running:

https://github.com/dradis/dradisframework#getting-started-git-release-recommended